# How to create numpy.ndarray from tuple iteration

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following loop

```
# `results` are obtained from some mySQldb command.

for row in results:
    print row
```

Which prints the tuples like this:

```
('1A34', 'RBP', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
('1A9N', 'RBP', 0.0456267, 0.0539268, 0.331932, 0.0464031, 4.41336e-06, 0.522107)
('1AQ3', 'RBP', 0.0444479, 0.201112, 0.268581, 0.0049757, 1.28505e-12, 0.480883)
('1AQ4', 'RBP', 0.0177232, 0.363746, 0.308995, 0.00169861, 0.0, 0.307837)
```

My question is from that iteration how can I create a bumpy nd.array that looks like this:

```
array([['1A34', 'RBP', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       ['1A9N', 'RBP', 0.0456267, 0.0539268, 0.331932, 0.0464031, 4.41336e-06, 0.522107],
       ['1AQ3', 'RBP', 0.0444479, 0.201112, 0.268581, 0.0049757, 1.28505e-12, 0.480883],
       ['1AQ4', 'RBP', 0.0177232, 0.363746, 0.308995, 0.00169861, 0.0, 0.307837]])
```

At the end the ndarray will have shape: `(4,8)`

Comment: Do you need to have `str` and `float` in one `array`? It can be done by `structured array` but it is not the ideal solution. Normal array only allow one type (`dtype` as it is known). Considering using `pandas`?

Comment: If `results` is a generator, you will need to convert it to a list first.  The reason is that numpy arrays need to know their size at creation time.  If you know the number of elements in `results`, then you can do something like `a = numpy.empty((n, 8), dtype='object')`, followed by: `for i, row in enumerate(results): a[i] = row`.

Comment: @AlokSinghal, not entirely true, there is a `numpy.fromiter` function.

Comment: @CTZhu thanks for mentioning that.  Although it seems like `fromiter` reallocates the array for every new element unless `count` is specified. *Edit*: just looked at the source code and it seems to do a 50% growth at every new allocation, so it might not be as bad as I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read it into a structured array:

```
In [30]:
a=[('1A34', 'RBP', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
   ('1A9N', 'RBP', 0.0456267, 0.0539268, 0.331932, 0.0464031, 4.41336e-06, 0.522107),
   ('1AQ3', 'RBP', 0.0444479, 0.201112, 0.268581, 0.0049757, 1.28505e-12, 0.480883),
   ('1AQ4', 'RBP', 0.0177232, 0.363746, 0.308995, 0.00169861, 0.0, 0.307837)]
np.array(a, dtype=('a10,a10,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4'))
Out[30]:
array([('1A34', 'RBP', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
       ('1A9N', 'RBP', 0.045626699924468994, 0.053926799446344376, 0.331932008266449, 0.04640309885144234, 4.413359874888556e-06, 0.5221070051193237),
       ('1AQ3', 'RBP', 0.044447898864746094, 0.20111200213432312, 0.26858100295066833, 0.004975699819624424, 1.2850499744171406e-12, 0.48088300228118896),
       ('1AQ4', 'RBP', 0.01772320084273815, 0.3637459874153137, 0.30899500846862793, 0.0016986100235953927, 0.0, 0.30783700942993164)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', 'S10'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4'), ('f4', '<f4'), ('f5', '<f4'), ('f6', '<f4'), ('f7', '<f4')])
```

You can have all of them in `object` `dtype`:

```
In [46]:

np.array(a, dtype=object)
Out[46]:
array([['1A34', 'RBP', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       ['1A9N', 'RBP', 0.0456267, 0.0539268, 0.331932, 0.0464031,
        4.41336e-06, 0.522107],
       ['1AQ3', 'RBP', 0.0444479, 0.201112, 0.268581, 0.0049757,
        1.28505e-12, 0.480883],
       ['1AQ4', 'RBP', 0.0177232, 0.363746, 0.308995, 0.00169861, 0.0,
        0.307837]], dtype=object)
```

but it is not ideal for the `float` values, also it may lead to undesired behaviors:

```
In [48]:
b=np.array(a, dtype=object)
b[0]+b[1] #addition for float values and concatenation for string values
Out[48]:
array(['1A341A9N', 'RBPRBP', 0.0456267, 1.0539268, 0.331932, 0.0464031,
       4.41336e-06, 0.522107], dtype=object)
```

`pandas` is also an alternative:

```
In [43]:
import pandas as pd
print pd.DataFrame(a)
      0    1         2         3         4         5             6         7
0  1A34  RBP  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000
1  1A9N  RBP  0.045627  0.053927  0.331932  0.046403  4.413360e-06  0.522107
2  1AQ3  RBP  0.044448  0.201112  0.268581  0.004976  1.285050e-12  0.480883
3  1AQ4  RBP  0.017723  0.363746  0.308995  0.001699  0.000000e+00  0.307837
In [44]:

pd.DataFrame(a).dtypes
Out[44]:
0     object
1     object
2    float64
3    float64
4    float64
5    float64
6    float64
7    float64
dtype: object
```

and it allows columns to have different `dtype`

Comment: Thanks for the panda suggestion. But I need numpy as required by scikit-learn.

Comment: You are welcome, in that case I will recommend coding the string values to dummy variables or factors (0, 1, 2, 3... ), so every thing can be fit into just ordinary `numpy` `array` of `float` `dtype`

Comment: the `undesired behaviour` is it solely for `object` data type? If I hardcode using your suggestion `dtype=[('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', 'S10'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4'), ('f4', '<f4'), ('f5', '<f4'), ('f6', '<f4'), ('f7', '<f4')])`, that side effect shouldn't occur right?

Comment: By the way the shape is `(4,)` not `(4,8)`. How cani I do it properly to get the latter shape?

Comment: Yeap, once you have the data in a `structured array`, the shape becomes `(4,)`. `8` disappeared (and instead you now have `8` fields, `f0` to `f7`).