# Shaping list of tuples into MxN dimensional ndarray in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following list of tuples,

```
a=[('1A34', 'RBP', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
   ('1A9N', 'RBP', 0.0456267, 0.0539268, 0.331932, 0.0464031, 4.41336e-06, 0.522107),
   ('1AQ3', 'RBP', 0.0444479, 0.201112, 0.268581, 0.0049757, 1.28505e-12, 0.480883),
   ('1AQ4', 'RBP', 0.0177232, 0.363746, 0.308995, 0.00169861, 0.0, 0.307837)]
```

What I want to do is to create a numpy nd.array with shape `(4,8)`
That looks like this:

```
array([['1A34', 'RBP', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       ['1A9N', 'RBP', 0.0456267, 0.0539268, 0.331932, 0.0464031, 4.41336e-06, 0.522107],
       ['1AQ3', 'RBP', 0.0444479, 0.201112, 0.268581, 0.0049757, 1.28505e-12, 0.480883],
       ['1AQ4', 'RBP', 0.0177232, 0.363746, 0.308995, 0.00169861, 0.0, 0.307837]])
```

I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(a, dtype=('a10,a10,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4'))
```

But it gives this shape instead:

```
In [37]: x.shape
Out[37]: (4,)
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

What you have already done is by far the most logical way to do it. To achieve what you are asking for you need to create an object array:

```
z = np.array(a,dtype=np.object)
print z.shape
# (4, 8)
```

What is looks like you are asking for is an array with variable data type by column. This is exactly what you achieve with `np.array(a, dtype=('a10,a10,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4'))`. Internally you can think of this array like an array of structs in C, i.e. a 1-d array of `dtype=('a10,a10,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4')` instances.

By using an `object` array you can request that numpy handles everything as a simple python object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any [harm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24482602/67405) using `object` instead of `('a10,a10,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4,f4')` ?

Comment: I would assume that using `object` would be inherently slower due to the its variable nature. The "harm" here would be somewhat unpredictable behaviour, as it will not always be obvious what bit width numbers have. e.g. half your `int`s could be 64-bit and the other half 32-bit.

Comment: Is there safer alternative than 'object' which produces the same results?

Comment: The safer alternative is your original example, which creates a `recarray`. What is the problem with using that? Is there really a requirement that you have a `(4,8)` shape? The `recarray` can be indexed just like a normal 2-d array.